# Replication to SQL Server and to Oracle not working for one database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication

I have a replication for many databases on one server to one SQL Server database and to Oracle. Replication for one database is not working while the other four databases are working. For SQL Server to SQL Server, there is one publication. For SQL Server to Oracle, there are 6 publications.

Also CDC is enabled on those databases.

The error messages are:

> Process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'DBname' 
>   Failed to insert rows into Change Data Capture .... 
>   The statement has been terminated.

When I look on the replication monitor tabs, Publisher to Distributor history is failing but Distributor to Subscriber history is working. The agent is failing.

Comment: Can you rebuild the replication?